# Is a Spell-Refueling Ring useless for a Warlock once reaching level 7?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, artificer, spell-slots, artificer-infusions

My Warlock just got a ring with the Artificer Infusion "Spell-Refueling Ring", this infusion states:

> While wearing this ring, the creature can recover one expended spell slot as an action. The recovered slot can be of 3rd level or lower. Once used, the ring can't be used again until the next dawn.

However, I am a Warlock which means that at 7th level, I literally do not have *any* 3rd level or lower spell slots. Does the ring thus become useless at this point and I should just give it to another party member?

Comment: I would almost disagree with this being a duplicate of the other two. For the Pearl of Power, it has specific text errata'd for the item. For Wild Magic Barbarian, the accepted answer is basically "RAW no, but it makes sense to use Pearl of Power to avoid awkward team syncs at level 7". This is a completely different item/ability, and therefor a different question even if the answers end up being similar.

Comment: I agree with the above - the Spell Refueling Ring has different wording and deserves a question of its own.

Comment: For me, the wording of the infusion is, for all intents and purposes, identical to the barbarian question. As such, it should remain closed. That question having "incomplete" answers is grounds for a bounty, not a duplicate